# Create user on Owncloud

Tags: owncloud

I searched, could not find a correct way to create new users on owncloud server. I tried to apply what [User Provisioning API](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_user/user_provisioning_api.html) says, but I always get this response:

```
<ocs>
 <meta>
  <status>failed</status>
  <statuscode>999</statuscode>
  <message>Invalid query, please check the syntax. API specifications are here: http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/open-collaboration-services. DEBUG OUTPUT: debug output: http request method: POST http request uri: /owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users%20-d%20userid=%22Frank%22%20-d%20password=%22frankspassword%22</message>
 </meta>
</ocs>
```

**My HTTP POST is:**

```
http://myuser:mypassword@ip_owncloud_server/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users -d userid="Frank" -d password="frankspassword"
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

first, the example given in the OwnCloud documentation is not complete.  It assumes you're using curl or other command line utility.  I got this script to work using jQuery AJAX:

```
<script>
function doMake() {
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://myowncloud.local:8080/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users',
  data: {'userid':'test', 'password':'test'},
  crossDomain: true,
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent('owncloud-dev' + ':' + 'password'))))
  }
}).done( function(data, status, xhr) {
    document.write(status);
}).fail( function(xhr, status, error) {
    document.write(status + ":" + error);
});
}
</script>
```

save the above as adduser.html in your root of your owncloud installed directory. replace the admin username/password in the Authorization requestHeader.

Answer (score 0):

From the message it looks like it's complaining about having quotes in your userid (and maybe password).  I know you took that from the example, but if you remove the quotes it will probably have a better chance of working:

```
http://myuser:mypassword@ip_owncloud_server/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users -d userid=Frank -d password=frankspassword
```

If you want to quote things to be protected from the shell, put the quotes around the whole argument like

```
http://myuser:mypassword@ip_owncloud_server/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users -d "userid=Frank" -d "password=frankspassword"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i am posting here an answer found here for anyone who would pass by this thread:
I found this searching for a similar solution my self on the Owncloud deve mailinglist : http://owncloud.10557.n7.nabble.com/User-Provisioning-API-PHP-Authentification-Error-td15927.html

It appears that using this in php w/ cURL:

```
<?php

$username = 'lukas';
$password = 'lukas';

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/master/ocs/v1.php/cloud/groups');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Hope it helps