# Creating User on ownCloud using php curl http post

Tags: php, api, authentication, curl, owncloud

There is all the relevant information present in broken form in the following links on owncloud related websites and from stackoverflow itself:

1. [User Provisioning Api](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/8.0/admin_manual/configuration_user/user_provisioning_api.html) - Owncloud
2. [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)
3. [Create user on ownCloud using Ajax Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536827/create-user-on-owncloud)
4. [User Provisioning - php Authentication error](http://owncloud.10557.n7.nabble.com/User-Provisioning-API-PHP-Authentification-Error-td15927.html)

I am trying to do something very simple :

1. I have setup an owncloud server in my localhost,
2. I have an html page that takes in string values of user name and password
3. I send the page request to be processed by the following php script.

   ```
   <?php
   echo "Begun processing credentials , first it will be stored in local variables" . "<br/>";

   // Loading into local variables
   $userName = $_POST['username'];
   $RRpassword = $_POST['password'];

   echo "Hello " . $userName . "<br/>";
   echo "Your password is " . $RRpassword . "<br/>";

   // Add data, to owncloud post array and then Send the http request for creating a new user
   $ownCloudPOSTArray = array('username' => $userName, 'password' => $RRpassword );

   $url = 'http://localhost/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users';
   $ch = curl_init($url);

   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ownCloudPOSTArray);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   echo "<br/>Created a new user in owncloud";
   ?>
   ```

I get the output like:

> Begun processing credentials , first it will be stored in local
>   variables
>  Hello Frank
>  Your password is frankspassword
>   failure 997 Unauthorised 
>  Created a new user in owncloud

I also tried to login to own cloud using following php script:

```
// Login As Admin
$ownAdminname = 'ownAdmin';
$ownAdminpassword = 'ownAdminPassword';

$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/owncloud');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$ownAdminname:$ownAdminpassword");
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Even this one fails.

So in short it doesn't work. I am also unable to login via similar script to owncloud. What is the proper way to do this ? What settings am I missing ? Can someone help please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question pertains to owncloud specifically, I created an account and posted a question linking this one to it in [owncloud forum](https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=32342).

There I was suggested by the owncloud master @RealRancor, the following,

> Just had another look, maybe its just easy to replace:
>
> $url = 'http://localhost/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users';
>
> with
>
> $url =
>   'http://adminuser:adminpass@localhost/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users';
>
> as shown in the documentation.

And amazingly it worked like a charm. So here is the entire modified php script:

```
<pre>
&lt;?php
echo "Begun processing credentials , first it will be stored in local variables" . "<br/>";

// Loading into local variables
$userName = $_POST['username'];
$RRpassword = $_POST['password'];

echo "Hello " . $userName . "<br/>";
echo "Your password is " . $RRpassword . "<br/>";

 // Login Credentials as Admin
 $ownAdminname = 'ownAdmin';
 $ownAdminpassword = 'ufi2016%%';


// Add data, to owncloud post array and then Send the http request for creating a new user
$url = 'http://' . $ownAdminname . ':' . $ownAdminpassword . '@localhost/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users';
echo "Created URL is " . $url . "<br/>"; 

$ownCloudPOSTArray = array('userid' => $userName, 'password' => $RRpassword );

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ownCloudPOSTArray);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "Response from curl :" . $response;
echo "<br/>Created a new user in owncloud<br/>";

// Add to a group called 'Users'
$groupUrl = $url . '/' . $userName . '/' . 'groups';
echo "Created groups URL is " . $groupUrl . "<br/>";

$ownCloudPOSTArrayGroup = array('groupid' => 'Users');

$ch = curl_init($groupUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $ownCloudPOSTArrayGroup);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "Response from curl :" . $response;
echo "<br/>Added the new user to default group in owncloud";

?>
</pre>
```

And here is the output:

```
Begun processing credentials , first it will be stored in local variables
Hello Frank
Your password is frankspassword
Created URL is http://ownAdmin:ufi2016%%@localhost/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users
Response from curl : ok 100 
Created a new user in owncloud
Created groups URL is http://ownAdmin:ufi2016%%@localhost/owncloud/ocs/v1.php/cloud/users/Frank/groups
Response from curl : ok 100 
Added the new user to default group in owncloud
```

Answer (score 1):

The owncloud documentation states that authentication is done by means of a basic HTTP Authentication header. What you are currently doing is sending the credentials as parameters to the API call. You need to add the following line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $RRpassword);
```

There's also a typo in CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER (`$curl` instead of `$ch`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo. I fixed it. But the error seems to persist.

Comment: Your code is fine now. I'm unfamiliar with OwnCloud but my guess is that either the credentials are incorrect or the user is not allowed to access the API.

Comment: Adding the line has no effect on the output since I still get unauthorized response. And you are right someone well versed with own Cloud API can help. And thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As your linked post ([Create user on Owncloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536827/create-user-on-owncloud)) shows you need to an basic auth header with some credentials.  You need to provide the admin credentials, afaict.

Comment: Yes I am trying to understand the settings, credentials etc. But I am not sure what is the correct way.